# Select values from smallest value in table with a group by

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a table that stores all the distances for a user from different points (like startplace1 to workplace 1, startplace1 to workplace 2, startplace1 to workplace 3, startplace2 to workplace1,startplace2 to workplace1)

```
Every line has an 'ID', 'AID' (=memberid), 'FROM', 'TO', 'DISTANCE'
```

[image: Tablestructure]

FYI: The fields 'from' & 'to' are maybe the same codes, but it isn't the same place (stored in another table, just for example dom1 is home).

I'm trying to **select** the **smallest distance** in a table **for every 'aid'** `(=memberid)` **for every startpoint** *(field from)* and some **other fields** related to the record with the smallest distance

I am using codeigniter, and this is what I already have:

```
$this->db->SELECT('aid,from,to,min(distance) as mindistance');
$this->db->FROM('distances');
$this->db->GROUP_BY('aid');
$this->db->GROUP_BY('from');
```

The query

```
SELECT `aid`, `from`, `to`, max(distance) as maxdistance FROM (`distances`) GROUP BY `aid`
```

[image: Results without order by]

This gives me the smallest distance, but the field 'to' isn't related to that record from the smallest distance. I tried also with ORDER_BY distance ASC but it's the same.

[image: Results with order by]

How can I select the field 'to' from the record with smallest distance, grouped by 'aid'-field and 'from'-field?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: "This gives me the smallest distance, but the field 'to' isn't related to that record from the smallest distance" .. from column could also not be related.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to a subquery which finds the minimum distance for each aid and starting point:

```
SELECT d1.aid, d1.`from`, d1.to, d1.distance
FROM distances d1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT aid, `from`, MIN(distance) as mindistance
    FROM distances
    GROUP BY aid, `from`
) d2
    ON d1.aid = d2.aid AND
       d1.`from` = d2.`from` AND
       d1.distance = d2.mindistance;
```